# Code coverage on JSX tests with Istanbul

Tags: code-coverage, reactjs, istanbul

I am trying to instrument my code to get some coverage up and running, but something is slipping through my fingers.

I launch `istanbul` with:

```
node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -u exports -R spec
```

And my `mocha.opts` looks like this:

```
app/assets/javascripts/components/**/*-mocha.jsx
--compilers jsx:mocha/compiler.js
```

Everything seems to run fine (the tests run, at least), but the only coverage that I get is on the files used to compile the JSX to JavaScript (used in `compiler.js`

```
compiler.js                 100%
jsx-stub-transform.js       65%
```

Terribly useful...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I use [gulp-jsx-coverage](https://github.com/zordius/gulp-jsx-coverage).

Here is my config as an example:

```js
var jsxCoverage = require('gulp-jsx-coverage');
gulp.task('test', ['lint', 'env:test'], jsxCoverage.createTask({
    src: ['src/**/*_test.js', 'src/**/*_test.jsx'],  // will pass to gulp.src as mocha tests
    istanbul: {                                      // will pass to istanbul
        coverageVariable: '__MY_TEST_COVERAGE__',
        exclude: /node_modules|tests|._test/         // do not instrument these files
    },
    transpile: {                                     // this is default whitelist/blacklist for transpilers
        babel: {
            include: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    },
    coverage: {
        reporters: ['text', 'lcov', 'cobertura'],    // list of istanbul reporters
        directory: 'coverage'                        // will pass to istanbul reporters
    },
    mocha: {                                         // will pass to mocha
        reporter: 'spec'
    },
    babel: {                                         // will pass to babel
        sourceMap: 'inline',                         // get hints in HTML coverage reports
        plugins: []
    }
}));
```

## *** UPDATE ***

Over time I decided to stop using `gulp-jsx-coverage`. My tests use the [`babel-rewire-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-rewire-plugin), and `gulp-jsx-coverage` was not instrumenting my files correctly, resulting in a coverage report that included a bunch of untested generated code. No bueno.

[See my 2nd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36776290/317951) for my current set up.

Comment: Yeah, that's an option, but I don't want to pull in gulp/grunt/broccoli just for the coverage.

I actually found a way to achieve what I was looking for and I will post the result here soon

Comment: Any word on that result @domokun? Love to see what you have.

Comment: I ended moving away from gulp-jsx-coverage. I'll update my answer with my current configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [isparta](https://github.com/douglasduteil/isparta) directly with [Babel 6](https://babeljs.io/) as follows:

### `npm test` command

```bash
BABEL_ENV=test babel-node node_modules/isparta/bin/isparta cover _mocha
```

### `.babelrc`

```json
{
    "plugins": [
        "add-module-exports",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-runtime"
    ],
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react",
        "stage-0"
    ],
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "plugins": [
                "rewire"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### `test/mocha.opts`

```
--compilers js:babel-core/register
--require test/init.js

src/**/*_test.js*
```

### `test.init.js`

```js
'use strict';

require('mock-require')('clappr');
require('testdom')('<html><body></body></html>', {
    React: 'react',
    localStorage: 'localStorage'
});
```

### `.istanbul.yml`

```yml
instrumentation:
  root: src
  excludes: ['*_test.js']
```

### select dependencies from `package.json`

```
"babel-cli": "^6.7.5",
"babel-core": "^6.7.2",
"babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
"babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0-rc-2",
"babel-plugin-runtime": "^1.0.7",
"babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.5.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"babel-register": "^6.7.2",
"babel-runtime": "^5.8.34",
"babel-template": "^6.7.0",
"babel-types": "^6.7.2",
"isparta": "^4.0.0",
"mocha": "^2.4.5",
```

### A note on .JSX files

I renamed all of my .JSX files to .JS, and here's why:

- I use [codecov](http://codecov.io) for hosted coverage reporting. This exposed the fact that while `coverage/lcov-report/index.html` showed the correct coverages, something in the JSON coverage files is missing for .JSX files. I was never able to figure it out. As far as I can tell, it's a bug in isparta or istanbul. I also tried `istanbul@1.0.0-alpha.2` and found it had the same issue.
- React used to recommend naming files .JSX for the benefit of transform utilites and editors. This is no longer a recommendation. As far as I can tell, it just doesn't matter anymore.

Since switching to .JS, I haven't seen any issues with tools including Atom and IntelliJ.

If you don't want to rename your files, you can add the following to my examples from above:

1. In the script, after `isparta cover`, add `--include \"src/**/*_test.jsx\"`.
2. To `.istanbul.yml`, add

```yml
extensions:
  - .js
  - .jsx
```