# ES6 + React + Karma + Coverage, show inaccurate values for code coverage

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, browserify, karma-coverage

I am trying to set up code coverage for an ES6 react project. I got karma with code coverage to work, but its showing inaccurate numbers for the code coverage. I currently don't have any unit test written and its showing coverage for files. Here is my karma config file

```
var istanbul  = require('browserify-istanbul');

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        base: './',
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false,
        autoWatch: true,
        frameworks : [ 'jasmine', 'browserify'],
        files: [
            'js/**/*.js'
        ],
        exclude: [ 'js/app.js' ],
        preprocessors: {
            'js/**/*.js': [ 'browserify' ]
        },
        browserify: {
            configure: function(bundle){
                bundle.on('prebundle', function(){
                    bundle
                        .transform(istanbul)
                })
            },
            transform: [ 
                ['babelify', { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }]
            ],
            debug: true,  // make stack traces readable.
        },

        reporters: [ 'progress', 'dots', 'coverage' ],
        coverageReporter: { 
            type : 'text', 
            dir : 'coverage/' 
        }
    });
};
```

The output is this

All files                           |    72.72 |    40.35 |    48.72 |    71.28 |

Comment: Try removing 'js/**/*.js' in files: [], and add in the tests folder instead.

Comment: @Darly Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having similar error...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code coverage on JSX tests with Istanbul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300782/code-coverage-on-jsx-tests-with-istanbul)